# Opening existing facebook app with a link to post

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have done with FBConnect framework . I have an option to post link to facebook in my application that I'm developing currently. I would like to know is there a way to open an existing facebook application that is already installed in the iPhone with a message to post. As I browsed I came to know that we could open the app using the following.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://<insert function here>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

but this only open and i am not able to post my dynamic text or link. And also I have to come back to my application When facebook application is closed. Can any one help me regarding this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not you are trying Facebook like feature within you app? please refer below link if you want in app facebook like feature

http://angelolloqui.blogspot.in/2010/11/facebook-like-button-on-ios.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=192575157422917